# Include WCF Service as part of an ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm a little bit confused, I want a `WCF` service that takes values and returns them as `XML`, to be bound to an `ASP.NET` project. So I guess I should create WCF Service Library instead of Application, then bind it to ASP.NET via "Add Service Reference"? And, if I got it correctly, that allows me to use service without any proxy classes?

P.S. Service method code that returns XML is something like

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContract]
[System.ServiceModel.Web.WebGet(
             UriTemplate = "men", 
             ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
Human[] getAll();
```

getAll() just generates an array of objects of Human class.

Comment: WCF **always** uses proxy classes - it's the cornerstone of the entire WCF architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you've got it partially correct, and partially sideways.

Yes, use a WCF Service Library to create the service.

No, don't use "Add Service Reference".

Instead, add the WCF Service Library as a normal project reference to the ASP.NET web application. Then create a "YourService.svc" file as the endpoint for the service.

```
<% @ServiceHost Service="MyNamespace.MyServiceImplementationTypeName" %>
```

See "[Deploying an Internet Information Services-Hosted WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx)".

You will also need some configuration in web.config. I don't know the best way to do this.

Comment: Well, what should be in YourService.svc then?